# /mnt directory is removed undesirable!

Tags: linux, partition, directory, restore

Accidentaly I have removed my `/mnt` directory... how can I restore it? with the exact permissions and etc???

This directory was empty.

Comment: Have you tried extracting it from your backup? Such a minor problem is an excellent "exercise" to see if your backup/restore strategy is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `/mnt` as root and:

```
chmod 755 /mnt
```

Comment: Any thing else? uid or ETC?

Comment: sudo mkdir /mnt, sudo chmod 755 /mnt, that's enough. owner and group are all 'root'

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all you have to do is to (as root)

```
 mkdir /mnt
 chmod 755 /mnt
```

The chmod is necessary to ensure that the mountpoint works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

From TLDP:

`This directory is provided so that the system administrator may temporarily
 mount a filesystem as needed. The content of this directory is a local issue
 and should not affect the manner in which any program is run`

This means you can simply create the `/mnt` directory as instructed in the other answers. Since there was nothing mounted under /mnt and it was empty, nothing to worry.